# Can a dwarf use great swords and longswords?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm preparing to play my first game of D&D and I want to play a dwarf fighter. The Players Handbook says they are small but heavy and can carry a lot. Is a dwarf fighter able to use a heavy blade, like a great sword or long sword?

Also I thought I saw somewhere in the Players Handbook the different regions the dawrfs live in but now I cant find it. I would like to use a dice to randomly select my region to help build my backstory/personality.

Comment: ^ Right, we are genuinely unable to give you any answers about mechanics until we know what edition you're playing, let alone give you recommendations.

Comment: Unfortunately, just *removing* the sentence that says you don't know which edition you'll be playing doesn't help. Besides, getting answers for a random edition won't help you anyway, because how each one works is different. Check with your group and find out for *sure* which one you'll be playing. Once you know which, edit this question to let us know which.

Comment: would love to check with my group if we all haven't played before.  we also dont have a DM we are in the possess of finding an experienced DM. so im just ganna go with that i can use a heavy blade based on what ive read. our group wants a fun RP experienced were we arent super concerned with the rule. would still like any additional info u can give with pros and cons as far as im aware all the editions  are pretty similar just give me a generalization if u must. THANK YOU!

Comment: The editions are superficially similar, but not similar in any way that really matters for mechanical questions. Something like what weapons a race can use and the pros and cons of weapon options changes regularly between editions.

Comment: Also (belatedly), welcome to the site and to the game! There are lots of people with experience across lots of role-playing games. You're going to get help here, I assure you. It's just been our experience that holding a question until uncertainties are sorted out will get you excellent answers; trying to suss them out dialogue-style as answers come in, question is revised, new answers try to address new details... just leads to poor answers.

Comment: Once you figure out more details on the edition you're playing, you might want to add what class your dwarf would be. A really great question would also put in there what you know as you've read in the book and why it's still unclear to you. Welcome to the hobby!

Comment: i dont have  aplayer handbood i got my info from a pdf of the 4th edition handbook. this is what i read that i have qustions about "Encumbered Speed: You move at your normal speed even when it would normally be reduced by armor
or a heavy load. Other effects that limit speed (such as difficult terrain or magical effects) affect you normally." it also says they are small compared to humans but are heavy(like in muscle ) plus Encumbered Speed is a racial trait for dawrfes but i think i have a misconception that a dawrf wouldnt be able to carrie a heavy blade but

Comment: based on what ive gathered from the book i think a they could use a heavy blade and only have minor disadvantages if any(please let me know if im wrong) i also know they have a boost in proficiency if they use a WarHammer or throwing hammer.

Comment: I'm closing this again. We can only entertain a question like this about a specific game/edition. (Randomly choosing an edition to try to make the question work doesn't count.) Without a game, this is just asking how dwarves work in general, which isn't on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Players Handbook says they are small

No, it does not. While Dwarves are short in terms of their description, the 4E Player's Handbook is very clear that they are Medium-sized creatures as far as the rules are concerned. As such, they have no special size-based restrictions on weapons relative to other Medium-sized creatures.

So yes, Dwarves would be just as able to use Greatswords and such as Humans or other Medium-sized creatures.